# Can I re-download my ps3 digital games to ps4 games?

Tags: ps3, ps4

I have a few games that I want to bring to PS4 when I get one.  It's Destiny, Advanced Warfare, and other digital games that are also on PS4.  So if its on ps4 and I have it on my ps3, can I download it again?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the developer and publisher of the game. If the game employs the `cross-buy` system, a PS4 license should automatically be added to your account when it is released, if you purchased the digital version of the game on the PS3.

This was the case with the recently released PS4 version of Journey, as well as with Flower, Spelunky HD, The Unfinished Swan and several other games.

You can confirm whether a released PS4 game supports cross-buy simply by visiting its store page in the PSN store. If you bought the game on PS3 and it supports cross-buy, instead of a **Buy** button with a price tag, there should be a **Download** button or **Options** button, which offers alternate download options in a drop-down menu.

Comment: Additionally there are a few games that originally did a $10 upgrade fee to go from the ps3 to ps4. A few that I can think of were Battlefield 4, CoD Ghosts and Assassins Creed. Not sure if they still do this or not since I have had my ps4 for a while now.

Comment: Indeed, many publishers offered such promotions for games released in the fall of 2013 and 2014, but IIRC all of them expired early the following year.